# Rainloop Installation and Configuration

Tags: debian

I am installing and configuring Rainloop, I am in the stage where I am supposed to log in as admin but impossible when I enter the addressee here is what it shows you had a solution

The tutorial I used: https://neptunet.fr/messagerie-debian/

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: Please don't - Rainloop is not being maintained anymore and has a stored XSS vulnerability [link](https://github.com/RainLoop/rainloop-webmail/issues/2172). Use Snappymail instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer I will try Snappymail I will keep you informed if I have problems for the installed

Comment: I can not install snappymail at all, I have too much trouble

Comment: Then maybe, you need to learn more about things before running your own mail server - which is not a task for beginners.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no choice, it is a project of end of year and must return the file on June 27

Comment: Please delete this question and stat over.