# Unable to connect to rainloop

Tags: linux, authentication

I am installing Rain Loop but when I want to connect to an account I have this message that appears "Authentication failed" have you ever seen this problem

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HisYP.png]

Comment: it would seem your credentials are not accepted by the system. That can have many reasons, from them actually being incorrect to something not working looking them up. You'll have to read the logs of what ever "RainLoop" is! My guess is you're using the wrong user name, but I really have no idea about what rainloop is or how it authenticates, against which authentication "database".

Comment: You shouldn't install Rainloop - its not maintained anymore and has a stored XSS vulnerability: https://github.com/RainLoop/rainloop-webmail/issues/2180 Consider using SnappyMail instead.

Comment: ... which I already told you [on your last question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706822/rainloop-installation-and-configuration#comment1337854_706822). I doubt your end of year project should be a publicly exposed vulnerable web service (you even give the adress in this question).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721261/snappy-mail-rainloop-authentication-failed/75315467 I hope the answer here will solve your problem.